# What's the equivalent in Delphi 3 of Supports for Interfaces?

Tags: delphi, legacy-code, delphi-3

I support an application written in Delphi 3 and I would like to put in some improvements to the source code while waiting for the opportunity to upgrade it to a newer version of Delphi. One of the things I would like to use is Interfaces. I know Delphi 3 already has the concept of Interfaces but I am having trouble finding out how to do the equivalent of

```
if Supports(ObjectInstance, IMyInterface) then
```

Comment: thats wrapper for IUnknown.QueryInterface http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682521(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write your own implementation of "Supports" function. In Delphi 2009 you can use

```
function MySupports(const Instance: TObject; const IID: TGUID): Boolean;
var
  Temp: IInterface;
  LUnknown: IUnknown;
begin
  Result:= (Instance <> nil) and
           ((Instance.GetInterface(IUnknown, LUnknown)
             and (LUnknown.QueryInterface(IID, Temp) = 0)) or
            Instance.GetInterface(IID, Temp));
end;
```

Test:

```
procedure TForm4.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Obj: TInterfacedObject;

begin
  Obj:= TInterfacedObject.Create;
  if MySupports(Obj, IUnknown) then
    ShowMessage('!!');
end;
```

Hope it will work in Delphi 3

Comment: Even better to just call it Supports and then when you move forward you just need to delete the declaration and all the calling code can remain the same.